# How to run migrations on a private RDS instance using Prisma?

Tags: database, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, prisma

I have a Node project which is using terraform for  provisioning and resource creation while serverless is used to deploy the functions. I'm using Prisma as the ORM with graphql. My problem is that I have a private RDS instance which is created through terraform and provisioned. Now I want to run the
`npx prisma migrate`
command but i'm not sure where do I run it as it is a private RDS instance and I can't run the migration command before terraform creates the resource.

I have tried codebuild as a build solution but unfortunately that requires a NAT gateway which I can't use as I need to work with public subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar scenario.

In my case, I created a bastion host (in the same VPC, public subnet) that can be accessed from my CICD tool. From the runner of the CICD tool, I created an SSH tunnel to access the RDS Serverless Aurora (in the same VPC, a private subnet, and NOT publicly accessible), and from there, I'm able to execute Prisma commands.

Hope this helps